# How do I resolve git merge conflicts on a submodule from `git stash pop`

Tags: git, git-stash, git-merge-conflict

I have a git repository with a submodule. I need to pop changes I've previously stashed. However, this is causing a merge conflict on the submodule reference.

I want to keep my changes from the stash, except for the submodule. For most code files, I can resolve the conflict by editing the conflicting file, but that doesn't seem to be an option for the submodule.

How can I resolve the merge conflict and still extract my changes from the stash?

```
$ git stash pop
warning: Failed to merge submodule some-submodule (commits don't follow merge-base)
Auto-merging some-code
Auto-merging some-submodule
CONFLICT (submodule): Merge conflict in some-submodule
```

---

```
$ git status
# On branch some-branch
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   some-code
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   both modified:      some-submodule
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As the `git status` comments say: `git reset HEAD some-submodule`.

By the way, after you've double checked that your tree and index are how they should be, you will probably want to `git stash drop`. `git stash pop` would normally do that, but doesn't when there are conflicts.

Comment: Ah, I had tried `git reset HEAD some-submodule/` unsuccessfully (shell tab-autocomplete adds a slash for the directory). I had to remove the slash.

Comment: i was doing a rebase and got this issue, simplly during the rebase conflict i did git reset HEAD some-submodule and added it to the changes and continued the rebase without any issue, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a cleaner solution but editing the stash eventually turned out to be simpler. YMMV.

```
git stash show -v > foo
$EDITOR foo
       (remove the fluff you don't want)
git apply < foo
```

In my case, simply deleting the "Subproject commit" and related diff lines worked.